# pprint dictionary returned as unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, pretty-print, pprint

I am using `requests` module. And, the data returned is unicode which contains the response(dictionary) from a server. Is there a way to pretty print the unicoded dictionary?

This response returned looks like this:

```
u'<<200:{"id":"12345","key_x":"41341e2277422","name":"xyz","key_y":"000566b8-1f52-5b38c","marked_for_removal":false,"max_capacity":3831609642556,"total_capacity":0,"total_reserved_capacity":0}'
```

or this:

```
u'>>GET https://x.x.x.x:8888/services/rest/abc : {'headers': {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'}, 'params': {}, 'timeout': 30, 'verify': False}'
```

I want to print it in the following manner:

```
u'<<200:
{"id":"12345",
"key_x":"41341e2277422",
"name":"xyz",
"key_y":"000566b8-1f52-5b38c",
"marked_for_removal":false,
"max_capacity":3831609642556,
"total_capacity":0,
"total_reserved_capacity":0}'
```

i.e. the json, in between, should be formatted and the string can remain as it is.

I've tried converting data to string and printing it but that doesn't work.

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(data.encode('utf-8'), width=1)
```

Comment: would pprint.pprint(response.json()) work?

Comment: `pprint` is for pretty printing python data structures (like dictionaries)

Comment: @Bemmu, most likely content-type is not `application/json`

Comment: OK, how about pprint.pprint(json.loads(response.content)) ? I'm just reading the docs from here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response

Comment: `response.content` will give you bytes which is not what you want since this is text data.

Comment: @Bemmu, as what avigil commented below, response is not a  valid json.

Comment: @Aditya, your update doesn't contain the values you need for the output. what's wrong here???? post a separate question for other output variation.

Answer (score 1):

`response` is of `str` type - contains the HTTP status code and actual JSON data structure.

```
import json
import pprint

# response is coming from requests, most likely Content-Type: text/plain 
# separate the status code '200' from the actual JSON data
status = response[:6]
data   = response[6:]

if '200' not in status:
   # Bail out, got an error
   exit(0)

parsed = json.loads(data.encode('utf-8'))

# Print output
print status
# Using pprint
pprint.pprint(parsed)
```

Comment: the response in the question doesn't exactly look like valid json (there is the leading `'<<200:`)

Comment: @avigil, most likely that's the HTTP STATUS CODE. 200 OK, will update

Comment: angry people :'(

Comment: Downvote probably because the `response.split(':')` is a list of too many values and throws too many values to unpack error

Comment: But, your answer is specific to a very particular case. The response can be a huge string and somewhere a json in between. For eg. `u'>>GET https://x.x.x.x:8888/services/rest/abc : {'headers': {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'}, 'params': {}, 'timeout': 30, 'verify': False}'`

Comment: @Aditya haven't seen your update. questions like this should be very specific to have specific answers

Comment: I'm upvoting this, seems like what the asker wanted. I think more information is needed about what kind of string may come before the JSON in order to split it more reliably.